# Boostrap novice wants two panels side by side on large screen, 1 panel over the other on small

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dokmanc/rak2fku2/3/) example where I have 2 panels and that each contain a couple of dropdown lists and associated labels. Right now, the panels are one over the other. I'd like the two panels to be side by side if there is sufficient room on the device else, for one panel to appear over the other, as they are now.

Here's the markup:

```
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Panel1</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ResidentStateType">State Type1</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="ResidentState" name="ResidentState">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="S">Subscriber</option>
                  <option value="M">Member</option>
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ResidentStateType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ResidentState">State1</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="ResidentState" name="ResidentState">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="AK">ALASKA</option>
                  <option value="AL">ALABAMA</option>
                  <option value="ETC">ARKANSAS</option>
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ResidentState" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Situs/Contract State</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SitusContractStateType">State Type2</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="SitusContractStateType" name="SitusContractStateType">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="R">Resident</option>
                  <option value="C">Client</option>
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SitusContractStateType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SitusContractState">State2</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="SitusContractState" name="SitusContractState">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="AK">ALASKA</option>
                  <option value="AL">ALABAMA</option>
                  <option value="ETC">ARKANSAS</option>
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SitusContractState" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dokmanc/rak2fku2/4/) is a JSFiddle link.

How would I do this?

I never used JSFiddle before, so I hope this works, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way:
Replace the two lines `<div class="panel-group">` by `<div class="col-sm-6 panel-group">`. When going under a certain width (depending of the configuration of bootstrap, default is 768px), the two panels will appear one above the other. Else, they are side by side.

The grid system is explained on the official website [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Once you understand it, you will be able to do whatever you want with your elements and position them wherever you want.

Comment: That worked. In order to get the effect that I wanted, I needed to have multiple containers classes, one for each "row" that could potentially wrap. For example, https://jsfiddle.net/dokmanc/rak2fku2/7/       Please let me know if this is not the way to do it.

Comment: I'm not a good enough front-end dev to be able to judge other's work. But I'd say that if the output is what you wanted, then it's fine, no matter how you achieved it.